# Select children in Cosmos DB with parent included in the result

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a product class that is stored in Cosmos DB together with its variants.

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Variant> Variants { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Variant
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to query a projection of the variants that includes the Product.

```
[DataContract]
public class VariantProjection
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the DocumentDB Linq api, but if it's not possible with this api any other API would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for [JOINs and Projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sql-query#a-idadvancedaadvanced-database-concepts-and-sql-queries) (might want to try the [Cosmos DB Query Playground](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo), it has scenarios for both).

It would be great to have a simple dataset to test but I believe something like this might help:

```
SELECT p as product, variant.name  
FROM p
JOIN variant IN p.variants
```

Keep in mind though that you are retrieving the entire Product for each variant. That's what you are trying to achieve in your C# code.